# How to read barcodes with a barcode scanner that does not emulate keyboard?

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port, barcode, barcode-scanner

EDIT: Okay, so I've moved on and made a fully working console app:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine($"Data Received: {indata}");
        indata = "";
    }
```

Now the problem is that when I try to do something similar in the UWP app -

```
public void InitScanner()
       {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM4")
            {
                BaudRate = 9600,
                Parity = Parity.None,
                StopBits = StopBits.One,
                DataBits = 8,
                Handshake = Handshake.None,
                RtsEnable = true
            };

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();

            tBlock_spState.Text = mySerialPort.IsOpen.ToString();

       }

        void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            tBlock_test.Text = indata;
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            InitScanner();
            

        }
```

It throws an System.IO.IOException with description "Too many posts on a semaphore" (sorry for the translation, I am using VS with Czech language). Does anyone know the reason why is this happening? Once again, can't find anything anywhere.

---

So, I've got a task to write a code, which could allow to read data from a barcode scanner that does not act like a keyboard and write it to a textbox. My thought was that it could be possible via System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class, but I have absolutely no idea how to make it work as it should. I am working on this in an UWP. I've tried this so far

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);

        void MethodName()
    {
        string s;

        if(!sp.IsOpen)
        sp.Open();

        while (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            s = sp.ReadLine();
            tBlock_test.Text = s;
        }

        sp.Close();
    }
```

And that is where I've ended and don't know what to do next, or even if this is somehow correct. Again, basic question, i know, but i am seriously stuck on this and cannot find solution anywhere. I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Only you know the exact model of barcode scanner, you'll have to look up a data sheet about it to see how it sends data (and also when it sends data). FYI: you may want to use the [`DataReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) event on the `SerialPort` so you don't have to manually poll it every x seconds

Comment: Is it possible to receive data from the barcode scanner as a prerequisite? If you haven't done that, please refer to this sample code. [Windows-universal-samples/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess/cs/](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/b1cb20f191d3fd99ce89df50c5b7d1a6e2382c01/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess/cs)

Comment: Why not use  [camera barcode scanner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-camerabarcode-get-started)?

Comment: @Nico Zhu because my task is to make this work for people, not camera scanner. That is matter of my boss, not mine

Comment: Please don't add SOLVED to your title. People will see if there's an (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've remade the app in the WPF template and tried the answer from here: [SerialPort reading cause error because of not owning thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443944/serialport-reading-cause-error-because-of-not-owning-thread) (Delegate + Invoke method) and it finally worked.